# Have to press go key twice on keyboard to login

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to build a login form. This is my password field xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:imeOptions="actionGo"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and the loginActivity where I am listening to the go key looks like this:

```
@OnClick(R.id.password_input)
public void Start() {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_input);
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                logIn();
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });
}
```

When I press the password field a keyboard pops up and then I have to hit the go key twice to call the logIn() function. What can be the reason for it and how do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you condition in onEditorAction like this:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_input);
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                logIn();

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I had created a test case, check with this one:

In your xml layout add:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

And in your Activity/Fragment code check with:

```
EditText edtInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtInput);
        edtInput.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);
        edtInput.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " GO ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Now run and check it's working for me, it should work for you also.

**Finally I got the solution with a silly mistake that we were doing, Can you please remove**

```
@OnClick(R.id.password_input)
public void Start() {
```

line of code if there is no usage, this is the issue which is not let all happen.

Add this code directly to your onCreate() of Activity, no need to give click event to EditText:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_input);
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                logIn();

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Still have to press the enter key twice to login. I need the login action to happen in the single click.

Comment: @Al Noman I have to make it work in a single click,its already happening when I press the enter key twice.

Comment: @Anant I had created a sample and checked it's working with me check updated answer.

Comment: @Anant I checked with your code also it is working like a charm. Please update your latest code what you had done.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your if condition like this .

```
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        Log.e(TAG, "enter_key_pressed");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@OnClick(R.id.password_input)
public void Start() {
    if (doublePressed) {
        //your intent or Operation
            return;
    }
    this.doublePressed = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click again to do”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doublePressed=false;                       
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@OnClick(R.id.password_input)
public void Start() { 
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_input);
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override 
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
            logIn(); 
            return true;
        } 
        return false;
    } 
}); 
}
```

Comment: Still have to press enter key 2 times at first launch of the app.